# Saving noSQL dataframe Pyspark to noSQL DB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nosql

I am looking for advice on the Big Data "goto" for saving a NoSQL dataframe from PySpark.

Hive is one way to saving this, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
columns = ["id", "gene","path", "respiration"]
data = [(1, "PDHA","3K00161","T"), (2, "aceE","K00163","F"), \
   (3, "PDHB","3K00161","T"),(4, "DLD","T01001","F")]
sampleDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(columns)
sampleDF.write.mode('overwrite') \
     .saveAsTable("mpathway")
```

I get the impression that Hive is rarely used,

1. what are the reasons?
2. What are the major alternatives for NoSQL for this operation? e.g. **MongoDB**

- What are the reasons for the alternative NoSQL method.